# how to join different specific lines of a file from within vi

Tags: text-processing, vim, vi

I'm looking for a solution about a "paste" problem on vi/vim .

How to join specific lines in a text file? I have a file like this:

```
15/10/2011 Revolution day
16/10/2011 About Rome
 - differents newspapers
  blogs an feeds
 :) hp
17/10/2011 Yep, another day
```

and I want to paste every line that does not start with a number. 
I've tried something like this, but it does not work:

```
:[!^[0-9]]!paste -d ' ' -s
```

Answer (score 3):

```
:%s/\(.*\)\n\(^[^0-9]\)/\1\2/g
```

If you want a space or something between, add it between \1 and \2.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it in two steps in VIM, if that's acceptable:

First, join all lines into a single line.

with the file open in VIM, issue the following keystroke: <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>G</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

- <kbd>V</kbd> = Visual Mode (linewise, rather than character-wise (<kbd>v</kbd>))
- <kbd>G</kbd> = highlight all lines
- <kbd>J</kbd> = Join all lines

Second, split your lines on the date format the resulting lines start with.

with the file open in VIM, issue the following command:

```
:%s#\([0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]\)#^M\1#g
```

This will search the single joined line for any string that matches NN/NN/N, where N = 0-9, which matches the date format that your lines start with, and will split on that match.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `v` with `join`.

```
:v/^[0-9]/-1,join
```

Broken down:

- `:v`    select any lines that do not match regular expression
- `/^[0-9]/`  any line starting with a digit
- `-1,`       the previous line to the current line
- `join`    combine the lines selected, separated by whitespace

Answer (score 0):

I'm talking about vim, this will not run in vi. Be aware of that.

What about

```
    :%v/^[^0-9]/d
```

to delete all lines in buffer , which start with a number.

```
    ggVG
```

to highlight all lines

```
    :w ! paste -d ' ' -s
```

and after that

```
    u
```

to go back to the starting point

Comment: It does not seems to work. Morevorer, I have stated an incorrect question. I want to join every line not starting by a number to the previous line starting with a number.

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
:g/^\d/,/^\d/-1j
```

and ignore error message **E16: Invalid range**